# How to convert split string to dictionary?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm making a programm which accepts a string in the following manner: `'Bob plays, draws Jane, Nicky lives in a house'`. Activity and a person doing this activity can be placed randomly. The person's name starts with an uppercase letter. Activities with names are always seperated with coma. Activites in dictionary should be always placed after the name. The output should be a dictionary in the following manner: `{'Bob': 'plays', 'Jane': 'draws', 'Nicky': 'lives in a house'}`.

I cannot get my head around how to firstly, split the string in blocks of persons, secondly, split these blocks in activity and person. I've always worked with simple dictionaries, where there is only one split, so this is quite complicated for me to even create a dictionary here.

Can anyone help me out with the solution, maybe give some tips? I will really appreciate this.

Comment: do activities always separate by the comma?

Comment: What should be the key and value for the yoda-style string  "in a house Bob lives" ?

Comment: You should first determine how the input string is going to be formatted, what separators you're going to use in order to determine the value associated with a name, and so on. For example, you could decide that each entry of the dictionary (key-value) is separated from other entries by a comma, then parse it following the "Key starts with uppercase, rest is value" logic and create the dict from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the names started with uppercase. so I made this code, hope to be helpful:

```
string = 'Bob plays, draws Jane, Nicky lives in a house'
splitedString = string.split(",")
finalDict = {}
for sentence in splitedString:
    splitedSentence = sentence.split()
    name = ''
    toDo = ''
    for word in splitedSentence:
        if(word[0].isupper()):
            name = word
        else:
            toDo = toDo + " " + word
    finalDict[name.strip()] = toDo.strip()
print(finalDict)
```

**Output**

```
{'Bob': 'plays', 'Jane': 'draws', 'Nicky': 'lives in a house'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to match the word with captial letter and create a dict using dict comprehension:

```
import re    
s = 'Bob plays, draws Jane, Nicky lives in a house'    
{re.search(r'\b[A-Z].*?\b', text.strip())[0]:text.replace(re.search(r'\b[A-Z].*?\b', text.strip())[0], '').strip() for text in s.split(',')}
```

Out:

```
{'Bob': 'plays', 'Jane': 'draws', 'Nicky': 'lives in a house'}
```

Or for Python 3.8 or newer:

```
{match:text.replace(match, '').strip() for text in s.split(',') if (match := re.search(r'\b[A-Z].*?\b', text.strip())[0])}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, in order to do this, unless you want to do natural language processing, you need to specify limitations on what constitutes names and what what constitutes  actions. For example, if you were to say that a name is a collection of latin alphabetical characters that starts with a capital letter, while an action in anything that is not a name, e.g. it cannot start with a capital letter, you could do something like this:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'^(.*)([A-Z][a-z]+)(.*)$')
a = 'Bob plays, draws Jane, Nicky lives in a house'

# split expressions by comma
b = a.split(',')
# create an empty dictionary to hold the result
d = {}

# process all comma-separated expressions
for i in b:
    # strip removes blank lines before and after the string
    i = i.strip()
    res = re.match(p, i)
    if res.group(1) != '' and res.group(3) != '':
        raise ValueError("Entry ({}) cannot be processed".format(i))
    person = res.group(2)
    action = res.group(1) if res.group(1) != '' else res.group(3)
    # set the dictionary entry with key - first element
    # and value - second
    d[person.strip()] = action.strip()
    
print(d)
```

Here, I simply use regular expressions to specify what is a name

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(s):
 ls = s.split(',')
 d = {}
 for e in ls:
    key = [w for w in e.split(' ') if w.istitle()][0]
    val = ' '.join([w for w in e.split(' ') if not w.istitle()])
    d[key] = val
return d
```